# Overload Resolution Ambiguity error in kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

How do I fix this Overload  error, I have Overload Resolution Ambiguity error, I sync it in my project and clean it and rebuild it but it's  get me bellow error ,I add main activity code in kotlin with 2 layout activity
Here is a photo of the error
[image: Overload Resolution Ambiguity error]

**Here is a main activity.kt**

```
package com.hussein.startup
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_food_details.view.*
import  kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.food_ticket.view.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var adapter:FoodAdapter?=null
var listOfFoods =ArrayList<Food>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // load foods


 listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.a))
   .....

    gvListFood.adapter =adapter

}


class  FoodAdapter:BaseAdapter {
    var listOfFood= ArrayList<Food>()
    var context:Context?=null
    constructor(context:Context,listOfFood:ArrayList<Food>):super(){
        this.context=context
        this.listOfFood=listOfFood
    }
    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val food = this.listOfFood[p0]
        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var foodView= inflator.inflate(R.layout.food_ticket,null)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setImageResource(food.image!!)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(context,FoodDetails::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name",food.name!!)
            intent.putExtra("des",food.des!!)
            intent.putExtra("image",food.image!!)
            context!!.startActivity(intent)
        }
        foodView.tvName.text = food.name!!
        return  foodView

    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return listOfFood[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
       return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {

        return listOfFood.size
    }

    }
 }
```

**Here is a layout xml**

**1-activity_food_details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FoodDetails">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFoodImage"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="50pt"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/c"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivFoodImage" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDetails"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**2-food_ticket.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="63pt"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="3pt">

<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFoodImage"
        android:layout_width="50pt"
        android:layout_height="50pt"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/c" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Coffe"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are defining `ivFoodImage` in both of your layouts.  And you are importing their definitions like so...

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_food_details.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.food_ticket.view.*
```

Consider changing the name in one of the layouts, or being explicit in the definition of `foodView`, or removing the import with `activity_food_details` if it's not being used.

**EDIT**

To clarify the possible solutions...

1. "Changing the name" - in one of your layouts, change ivFoodImage to something else like `ivFoodImage_Details`.
2. "removing the unused import" - self explanatory and a good practice.
3. "being explicit" - remove the import for the one you want to be explicit with and then do what the OP is doing i.e., `var foodView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.food_ticket,null)`, explicitly loading from `food_ticket` in this case.

The concept of using the same name in multiple layouts is not bad (think in terms of interfaces and injection).  But the `kotlinx.android.synthetic` is a syntactic candy to make things less verbose.  It gets in the way of the goal here.

Here is yet another alternative.  If you are trying to have a layout implement a sort of "Interface", consider wrapping each layout with its own Kotlin class and have the class implement the interface instead.  This might get tedious if you have lots of such layouts, so "pick your poison", this is just another idea.

Last, see @Daniel Wilson's answer.  It avoids the compiler error and makes you specify the namespace for which `ivFoodImage` you want to use.

Comment: Interesting. So there is no elegant way to give views the same id across layout xmls? I think having multiple similar views with the same ids and `findViewById()` not care where the id comes from is still useful. Maybe a `typealias` would be useful here.

Comment: Hi,guy, the same as you ... thanks for you saving my time

Comment: can someone show me how I can be explicit in the definition of foodView as explained in the answer?

Comment: @Les Getting this error when using ConstraintLayout and using the layout tag with id https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676415/how-to-include-constraint-layout-to-another-constraint-layout-and-set-constraint

Answer (score 8):

[Referencing this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061869/1866373), you can specifically import the ID you want and name it using Kotlin's `as` keyword

```
package XXX

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.num_info_inet_plus_pack.view.circle as inetViewCircle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.num_info_pack.view as circle
//...
val inetView = activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.num_info_pack, parent, false)
inetViewCircle.setBackgroundResource(background)
```

Answer (score 4):

This means that resource ids in java files from xml files are not properly imported, or are imported with wrong xml resource id files because of same name.

Suppose for

```
----activity_login 
----activity_main
```

there is a textview with same id.

Kotlin imports tries to search every xml file ids, and the id gets wrongly imported.

**Solution**:: Remove all imports after copy/paste and follow `alt+enter` one by one.

Answer (score 0):

@DanielWilson answer is correct. If you have 2 similar layouts, you don't need to rename equal fields in order to make them unique.

But you have to import all equal fields one-by-one renaming them. So, if you haven't renamed *in layouts*, you would rename them *in code*. For instance,

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row_profile_balance_refill.amount as refill_amount
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row_profile_balance_refill.reason as refill_reason
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row_profile_balance_withdrawal.amount as withdrawal_amount
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row_profile_balance_withdrawal.reason as withdrawal_reason
```

I got into situation where Kotlin couldn't resolve which field corresponds to which layout.

[image]

Strange, but I couldn't use `refill_amount` and `refill_reason`. Then I used old Java method `findViewById()`. So, a class at the picture turns to:

```
class RefillViewHolder(itemView: View) : AbstractViewHolder(itemView) {
    val amount: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount)
    val reason: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.reason)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Les' answer above, I usually like keeping my naming conventions simple like calling a RecyclerView's id @+id/recyclerView. If I have an Activity called ExampleActivity.java with layout R.layout.activity_example, I don't want to directly import every single view in that layout, I'd rather just import all the views from the layout. So I'd just import the whole file in the activity:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_example.*
```

to import all the views from my activity's layout file since I usually access all of them anyways. If your layout file includes other layouts, you'll have to import those layouts separately too. So if i use a header layout included in my activity_example.xml file, i'd import that whole layout file

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.header_layout.*
```

Answer (score 0):

**The simple answer I found:**

When you copy the code having layout ids, in imports i found

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity.main*
```

This is irrelevant to my activity. In your case it is

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.food_ticket.view.*
```

Just remove it. That's it.

You just have to ensure it should match your current activity so that it will work. If not matching with your activity then simply remove it. Android studio will automatically import the current activity for you.

And the issue gets resolved easily.

Answer (score -1):

package com.example.businesscard

```
@Composable
fun GreetingText(
    myName: String,
    job: String,
    phone: String,
    gmail: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = myName,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
            lineHeight = 46.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = job,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 4.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = phone,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 4.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = gmail,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 4.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

how to fix  overload resolution ambiguity error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35713952)

Comment: If you have a question, post another one