# Kotlin extension view binding : "Overload resolution ambiguity.." error on editor on custom button

Tags: android, kotlin-extension

I am using the new *kotlin extension* for view binding but I am having this annoying warning red underline message `custom_button.setOnClickListener{}` stating **"Overload resolution ambiguity.."**

I am trying to use my custom button class which extends `Button` class.

> **My activity class**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        custom_button.setOnClickListener {  }
    }
}
```

> **Custom button class**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.widget.Button

class CustomButton(context: Context?) : Button(context)
```

> **XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.myapplication.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/custom_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you should full xml and mainactivity code?

Comment: Check solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46045482/10271334

Comment: @JeelVankhede I do not have duplicate id.

Comment: @SonTruong I updated the code